# How to fix EPerm issue related to editing files while expo-webpack is running on Windows

Tags: windows, expo

So I've been running into an issue when running a local expo-webpack server on Windows. Sometimes I get a few changes sometimes only one change on a file then I get this error EPerm cannot perform operation, lstat  with the filename and a ~ afterwards.

I've tried to change security permissions to no avail. It seems to be a windows only problem as far as I can tell because when running in WSL it works as well as on a separate mac machine. I also removed read-only but after I check again it says read-only again. I also tried the version of node that works on WSL.